# The problem is with the x and y position, where the mouse can be click outside of the button

Tags: ruby, libgosu

The goal for this program is that the mouse must be clicked on the green rectangle shape which change the window background color to yellow or back to default color and the issue is that the color can also be change from outside of the rectangle.

The mouse click should only apply inside the rectangle.

The problem is with the x and y position in the if else statement i guess?

Also the 'Click Me’ text does not appear on the button .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7ScE.png)

The correct x and y position for the button is in this table, click the link.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'gosu'

# Instructions:  This code needs to be fixed and finished!
# The "Click Me" text is not appearing on the button, also
# the mouse_y co-ordinate should be shown along with the mouse_x one
# finally, a user has noticed the sometimes the button action occurs
# when you click out side the button area and vice-versa.


# determines whether a graphical widget is placed over others or not
module ZOrder
  BACKGROUND, MIDDLE, TOP = *0..2
end

# Global constants
WIN_WIDTH = 640
WIN_HEIGHT = 400

class DemoWindow < Gosu::Window

  # set up variables and attributes
  def initialize
    super(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT, false)
    @background = Gosu::Color::WHITE
    @button_font = Gosu::Font.new(20)
    @info_font = Gosu::Font.new(10)
    @locs = [60,60]
  end


  # Draw the background, the button with 'click me' text and text
  # showing the mouse coordinates
  def draw
    # Draw background color
    Gosu.draw_rect(0, 0, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT, @background, ZOrder::BACKGROUND, mode=:default)
    # Draw the button
    Gosu.draw_rect(50, 50, 100, 50, Gosu::Color::GREEN, ZOrder::TOP, mode=:default)
    # Draw the button text
    @button_font.draw("Click me", 60, 60, ZOrder::MIDDLE, 1.0, 1.0, Gosu::Color::BLACK)
    # Draw the mouse position information
    @info_font.draw("mouse_x: #{@locs[0]}", 0, 350, ZOrder::TOP, 1.0, 1.0, Gosu::Color::BLACK)
  end

  # this is called by Gosu to see if should show the cursor (or mouse)
  def needs_cursor?
    true
  end

  # If the button area (rectangle) has been clicked on change the background color
  # also store the mouse_x and mouse_y attributes that we 'inherit' from Gosu
  # you will learn about inheritance in the OOP unit - for now just accept that
  # these are available and filled with the latest x and y locations of the mouse click.

  def mouse_over_button(mouse_x, mouse_y)
    if ((mouse_x > 50 and mouse_x < 150) or (mouse_y > 50 and mouse_x < 100))
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  # Where is mouse_x and mouse_y defined

  def button_down(id)
    case id
    when Gosu::MsLeft
      @locs = [mouse_x, mouse_y]
      if mouse_over_button(mouse_x, mouse_y)
        @background = Gosu::Color::YELLOW
      else
        @background = Gosu::Color::WHITE
      end
    end
  end
end

# Lets get started!
DemoWindow.new.show
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in the logic of the mouse position detect in the mouse_over_button method. The mouse is over the button region when all the criteria are met. It should read:

```
def mouse_over_button(mouse_x, mouse_y)
  mouse_x > 50 and mouse_x < 150 and mouse_y > 50 and mouse_x < 100
end
```

I also removed the redundant "if" construct as it was not needed.

Comment: It should be `&&` instead of `and` (which is is control flow operator).

Comment: `mouse_x.between?(50, 150) && mouse_y.between?(50, 100)`

Comment: Yes now it is in the correct position but the button does not display the text 'Click Me'

Answer (score 0):

For the Displaying of the text on the button all you have to do is change the ZOrder of the button text from MIDDLE to TOP on line 40 since the buttons layout order is ON top of the button text. I see you had this question from Intro. To Programming unit from Swinburne Uni. Im a first year there. Good Luck ;)